# Intellij : Find usages , but exclude test files from results

Tags: intellij-idea

Anyone knows how to exclude test files from find usages results ?

Like everything that is under : src/test/

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Intellij Ultimate 11 version has an option to search in "Project production files".

Just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> on a usage and look on Scope.

Comment: "Project production files" is also in the community version.

Answer (score 152):

In the Find usages result panel, you can group by test/production. There is a button for that.

[image]

Comment: This is just the best

Answer (score 75):

I found this answer extremely helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45958976/5449497

By putting `!*Test.java` into the **File Mask** textfield you can exclude Testfiles from your search results within the project.

Comment: Great tip for the `Find in Path` dialog (most of the other solutions here are for the `Find usages` panel/section).

Comment: This will only work if your test file ends with text Test

Answer (score 44):

**IntelliJ IDEA Skip tests files pattern**

You are able to create a custom search [Scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scope.html)

> A scope is a subset of files, packages and/or directories in your project, to which you can limit the application of specific operations, e.g. search, code inspection, insertion of copyright notices, etc.

```
Edit -> Find -> Find Usages Settings...
```

[image]

Use pattern

`!file:*Test.java` or `!file:*Test.java&&!file:*Tests.java` or `!test:*.*&&!test:*`

All your scopes you can find

```
Android Studio -> Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior -> Scopes
```

Also you can customise a pattern by using [syntax](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scope-language-syntax-reference.html)

[[Skip generated files pattern]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50839123/4770877)

Comment: In the current version of Jetbrains' IDEs, you have to click the "..." next to the scope dropdown and add a scope before you can fill in the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, you can combine different conditions like this
*.java,!*Test.java
-> That is present in *.java files and do not include search from *Test.java files

Answer (score 1):

BTW: I am using  the  latest version of  Intellij 2020.3

steps to follow:

1. Create your own Scope (Settings –> Appearance & Behaviour –> Scopes)

[image]

2. Display Find Usages Settings dialog (Ctrl + Alt + Shift + F7)
3. Select your custom scope from the dropdown menu and click on Find
4. For the second time, Display Find Usages Settings dialog (Ctrl + Alt + Shift + F7)