# Android Studio : Exclude files in build folder from search result

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an Android Studio project in which I have multiple modules, each of those module depending on a share module. And let's say that this share module has an xml file call **sample.xml**

When I search to open file with **Navigate -> Files...** and type "sample.xml", I'll get

1. Share/src/main/res/values/sample.xml
2. ModuleA/build/intermediates/exploded-arr/.../res/values/sample.xml
3. ModuleB/build/intermediates/exploded-arr/.../res/values/sample.xml
4. ModuleC/build/intermediates/exploded-arr/.../res/values/sample.xml
5. ModuleD/build/intermediates/exploded-arr/.../res/values/sample.xml
   ...

Since the files in build folder are generated and we shouldn't edit them, there is no reason why I want to include them in my search result. Is there anyway I can exclude them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore R.java fies in Find results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22973939/ignore-r-java-fies-in-find-results)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743242/how-do-i-get-android-studio-to-stop-returning-generated-code-in-search-results

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get Android Studio to stop returning generated code in search results?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743242/how-do-i-get-android-studio-to-stop-returning-generated-code-in-search-results)

Comment: @CrandellWS the topic you are referring is talking about "Find in Path" while mine is talking about "Navigate > File...". With Find in Path you can specify custom scope and save it but you can't do that with "Navigate > FIle...".

Comment: I see you are correct my mistake

Comment: WTH, why the hell doesn't android studio have "mark directory as excluded" like pretty much every other JetBrains IDE?

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Because they've delegated the responsibility to Gradle in order to avoid conflicts. AS is much tighter integrated with Gradle than IDEA for instance. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46036948/507339

Answer (score 83):

To put it simply, and to actually exclude build paths from your search, you need to follow Frank's answer point 1 and 2, then because there's no suitable scope that actually exclude the build folder, simply do this:

Inside the "Find in Path" dialog (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>):

1. tap the ... to configure a scope
2. click the <kbd>+</kbd> button, choose local scope
3. give your new scope a name
4. enter `!file:build//*` in the pattern
5. tap OK and test your new scope

[image]
If you further want to have a scope for a single module, create a scope for your module (including recursively your module path), then add this at the beginning of your pattern:

```
!file:build//*&&
```

For example, a scope for 2 modules:

```
!file:build//*&&file[MODULE1_DIRECTORY_NAME]:*/||file[MODULE2_DIRECTORY_NAME]:*/
```

Only got the full answer reading Frank's answer and post #7 from issue reported here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61488

Comment: Are you sure this answers his question? He asked about filtering CTRL+SHIFT+N, you gave him the CTRL+SHIF+F answer. I need the Navigate > File solution too. Anybody knows how to?

Comment: The two module example is missing parentheses: it should be `!file:build//*&&(file[MODULE1_DIRECTORY_NAME]:*/||file[MODULE2_DIRECTORY_NAME]:*/)`, otherwise the `build` subfolder of module2 is not excluded.

Comment: People aren’t reading correctly. Find in Path (and similar) are *not* the same as Navigate -> Class / File / Symbol, etc. The former supports scopes, the later, mysteriously, doesn’t.

Comment: For some reason this still gives me itermediates and generated files, even though the build folder is their parent. This 
seems to get rid of all unwanted results: "!file:build//*&&!file:*intermediates*/&&!file:*generated*/". However, the original question is regarding a file name search (not file content search), which I also have not found an answer for.

Comment: I use `!file:build//*&&!file:app//build//*&&!lib:*..*` pattern to exclude build and lib folders

Comment: error with "package pattern expected at position 17" this might be out of date...

Answer (score 25):

> Android Studio  ->  Appearance & Behavior -> Scopes -> + -> add scope
>   -> local -> set a custom name & set Pattern

`!file:*intermediates*/&&!file:*generated*/&&!file:R.java`

[image]

Answer (score 15):

You can create a **Custom Scope** which defines the set files that you want to search and allows you to exclude those that you do not want to search.

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to present the **Find
   in Path** dialog.
2. Under **Scope** select **Custom**
3. If one of the Scopes that are present in the drop down list does not restrict the file search according to your needs you can create your own Custom Scope. To do this click on the <kbd>...</kbd> button.
4. Then Click on the <kbd>+</kbd> button and select **Local**
5. In the pane on the right you can Include and Exclude individual files and Recursively include or exclude all files beneath a folder.

You can then use your Custom Scope to constrain the files that are searched when you do **Find in Path**.

Comment: Seems a little too generic to actually answer the question

Answer (score 10):

Had the same issue.
Found that these 'build' folders were marked as sourceFolder in the module's .iml file.

Removing all such entries fixed the problem

```
<sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/..." ..../>
```

Comment: When i was restart AndroidStudio,The module's iml will restore...How can i do

Answer (score 9):

To exclude all build folders from all modules use this pattern:

```
!file:*build*/
```

If you want exclude also all libraries, simply use this pattern:

```
!file:*build*/&&!lib:*..*
```

---

**Detailed description:**

1. In the Find window click on the **Scope** tab, then on **three dots button**:

[image]

2. **Plus** button -> **Local** -> Enter name

[image]

3. Add the desired **pattern**:

[image: Search scopes]

4. Save and **enjoy**!

Comment: Hello!  If I can see my ```Gradle: some.sdk:@aar``` in project window, is it possible to set it as a scope so that I can search in this scope?

Comment: This is the one that worked for me, the others didn't.

Answer (score 8):

This problem seems to be fixed in later versions of Android Studio, but should it reoccur or you have a special folder setup:

You need to modify the exclusion list through gradle with the help of the [idea plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html)

Example:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'

idea.module {
    excludeDirs += file('build/')
}
```

Then run task `ideaModule` to regenerate the `.iml` file with the exclusion line described in [Corwin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31293830/507339)

Comment: Works great! I wanted to exclude my `node_modules` directory from the file find so I just added `excludeDirs += file('node_modules/')`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

None of the patterns in these answers worked for me. This one did: `!file:*/build/intermediates//*`

Answer (score 0):

You can use exclude pattern like

```
!file:build//*&&
```

[[How to add a new pattern follow and skip tests pattern]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49238500/4770877) 
[[Skip generated files pattern]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50839123/4770877)